# has there been any developments on what energy really _is_?

Tags: energy, history

Since high school I was always confused by the concept of energy, in recent years I tried multiple times to understand what it actually is and I failed to grasp it from the common definitions (why does the joule have so many definitions on so many apparently unrelated physical phenomena?).

Recently I stumbled upon this quote from Feynman, addressing ***exactly*** what my problem was.

> There is a fact, or if you wish, a law governing all natural phenomena
>   that are known to date. There is no known exception to this law – it
>   is exact so far as we know. The law is called the conservation of
>   energy. It states that there is a certain quantity, which we call
>   “energy,” that does not change in the manifold changes that nature
>   undergoes. That is a most abstract idea, because it is a mathematical
>   principle; it says there is a numerical quantity which does not change
>   when something happens . . . it is a strange fact that when we
>   calculate some number and when we finish watching nature go through
>   her tricks and calculate the number again, it is the same. It is
>   important to realize that in physics today, we have no knowledge of
>   what energy “is.” We do not have a picture that energy comes in little
>   blobs of a definite amount. It is not that way. It . . . does not tell
>   us the mechanism or the reason for the various formulas.
>   source: *The Feynman Lectures on Physics Vol I, p 4-1*

So my question is: Feynman died in 1988, do we today, 30 years later, have any better insights on what energy *really is*?
does this quote still hold?

Comment: There is a well-know relation between conservation of energy and invariance of spacetime under "translations" in time.  If you search for "energy conservation" + "time translation" here or elsewhere, you'll surely find good existing descriptions.  If you are asking for something somehow "more fundamental" than that, then I would wonder what you could possibly have in mind.

Comment: Almost literal duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/249011/50583, see also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/138972/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3014/50583